# probability of m to be a primality radius of n

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote by  $ r_{0}(n) : =\inf\{r\geq 0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\} $ . Then Cramer's model allows to write that the probability  $ P((n-k,n+k)\in\mathbb{P}^{2})=\dfrac{c_{k}}{\log^{2}n} $ and  $ r_{0}(n)=\inf\{m,\sum_{k=0}^{m}\dfrac{c_{k}}{\log^{2}n}\geq 1\} $.

Would a proof that  $ \forall k, c_{k}>0 $ entail that  $ r_{0}(n)=O(\log^{2}n) $?

Comment: I decided to crosspost this question to Mathoverflow.